# What is the difference adding index, and adding index with unique true in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an account_users table, which has account_id and user_id. So I added an index at the DB level for maintaining unique records

```
add_index :account_users, [:account_id, :user_id], unique: true
```

Sometimes I am getting this exception, even though I am sure that I am entering the right combination of account and user, I mean a record which is not present

And sometimes it magically works and sometimes I am getting the below error

`"ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"account_users_pkey\"\nDETAIL:  Key (id)=(6) already exists.\n: INSERT INTO \"account_users\" (\"account_id\", \"user_id\", \"created_at\", \"updated_at\", \"common_role_id\", \"added_by_user_id\") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING \"id\"","duration":25.14,"view":0.0,"db":9.59}`

I would like to know if `unique: true` is the culprit here.

Comment: yes. `unique` is the culprit. `unique` adds the constraint on the field, saying that `account_id` and `user_id` together should always be unique, making it sort of a secondary key.

Comment: just having index without `unique` will offer the indexing of the fields combination, giving you the good performance in search and joins, but it will allow duplicates

Comment: "I would like to know if unique: true is the culprit here" - not directly. Your data is the culprit (which doesn't satisfy the requirements of this unique index)

Answer (score 0):

Unique constraint restrict you to add any duplicate entry in your db table. So if you have already have any duplicate entry in your table then unique constraint will not be added.

You must first make them unique first.